# Error running java program using processing dependency. StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, processing

I am getting an error when running java program using processing core v 3.3.7.
I tried other versions, but it didn't help.

The error I get is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 2
at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit>(PApplet.java:120)
```

The code is provided below:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ProcessingTest extends PApplet {

  @Override
  public void settings() {
      size(200, 200);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw() {
      background(0);
      fill(255, 0, 0);
      ellipse(100, 100, 100, 100);
  }

  public static void main (String... args) {
      ProcessingTest pt = new ProcessingTest();
      PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{"ProcessingTest"}, pt);
  }

}
```

I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: You're using a version that's over 2 years old. This may well just be a bug that's been fixed since then. Is there any reason you're not using a more recent version?

Comment: Isn't that the latest version of processing core? not really sure, but I looked at maven repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core) and that was the latest version there. maybe you could give me a working version.

Comment: Well I was just looking at https://github.com/processing/processing/releases. See https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5666. I suggest you download it locally, basically.

Comment: Yeah, this may work locally, but my hosting provider requires it to be a maven dependency as I have no possibility of including jar files in the project when deploying the application. This is done automatically by my hosting on build. So if anyone has other suggestions or solutions please suggest.

Comment: While there are potentially workarounds for *this* bug, what do you intend to do next time, if there's something that *can't* be worked around? Not being able to upgrade to another dependency feels like a very significant limitation. You might want to investigate publishing a Maven package of the latest version of Processing Core yourself - not to Maven Central, but some other more personal Maven server, if possible. Unless this is a very short-lived project, I would avoid accepting "yeah, I can never update this, ever" as a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough I couldn't replicate your issue.

Is your class in a package ? If so, might be worth passing the full class path including the package. e.g:

```
PApplet.runSketch(new String[]{ProcessingTest.class.getCanonicalName()}, pt);
```

you can also try:

```
PApplet.main(ProcessingTest.class.getCanonicalName());
```

Additionally, it's worth mentioning what OSX you're on and what JDK you used to compile, and what your machine outputs when calling `System.getProperty("java.version");`.

Having a quick skim through Processing source code I spotted [this line](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L133):

```
javaPlatform = parseInt(version.substring(0, version.indexOf('.')));
```

Depending on your OS this might a basic bug parsing an unexpected string.